# RestTemplate - Put - Wrong Accept Header - Workaround needed

Tags: android, resttemplate

I've been using RestTemplate for a while and have always been satisfied !

But now It sucks.

I used to make my put like this :

```
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());
        restTemplate.put(URI, object);
```

Usually my server was accepting format in the URL in a Ruby way : resource.json

But now I'm consuming a server who is not doing so anymore. I need to use Header to deal with format.

Everything is ok, restTemplate set content-type to application/json but don't set the Accept header. So my server is issuing a 406 error because default format is HTML, and he don't render html.

So, does anybody has a workaround for putting both content and accept header to json and adding a json formatted body ?

Comment: try experimenting with the headForHeaders method in the RestTemplate. it returns a map, so try adding the accept header

Comment: also, check out this [issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-5866?focusedCommentId=51932&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-51932)

Comment: let me know if it works and i'll move it to an answer

Comment: It do work ! Go for answer ;)

Comment: Here is my code sample : `RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter());

            HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
            requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
            HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<T>((T) parameter, requestHeaders);
            
            restTemplate.exchange(URI , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, null );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the headers from the RestTemplate object and add what you need to it (since the headers are nothing more than a map).

Here is the sample code provided by Dam after he got it working:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new GsonHttpMessageConverter()); 
HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(new MediaType[] {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON}));
HttpEntity<T> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<T>((T) parameter, requestHeaders);  
restTemplate.exchange(URI , HttpMethod.PUT, requestEntity, null );
```